# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4, 25001] Seems like header does not get recognized?

Tags: python, header, regression

Does someone knows what is the problem? It seems like the column names are not recognized as header. Below is my code with in bold corresponding errors. I want to write a function that trains a logistic regression by splitting dataset into train and test sets (70% of data training and 30% of data for tests). Thank you in advance.

Import

`import numpy as np`

`import pandas as pd`

`import csv`

`from    sklearn.linear_model import Logistic Regression`

`from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix`

`from sklearn import tree`

`from    sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression`

`from sklearn.metrics    import confusion_matrix`

`from sklearn.datasets import data`

`from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`

Load dataset, seprate data in columns and give columnnames:

`colnames=["Watermark", "Micro-print", "Ultraviolet fields", "Magnetic fields", "Diameter","Target"]`

`Dataset=pd.read_csv("/Users/David/Documents/Python Assignment2/data-banknote.csv", sep=',', names=colnames)`

`Dataset.index=np.arange(1,len(Dataset)+1)`

Define TrainData and TestData

`TrainData= Dataset["Watermark"],Dataset["Micro-print"],Dataset["Ultraviolet fields"],Dataset["Magnetic fields"],Dataset["Diameter"]`

`TestData= Dataset["Target"]`

Show head of the dataset

`TrainData.head()`

`TestData.head()`

**Error is given that TrainData has no header?**

Splitting the dataset

`TrainData_train,TrainData_test,TestData_train,TestData_test = train_test_split(TrainData,TestData,test_size=0.3,random_state=0)`

**ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4, 25001]?**

Comment: if you don't have headers in the file, then pass `pd.read_csv(... ,header=None)`.